# Obtaining marginal PDFs through change of variables

Tags: probability, distributions, density-function

Given a random variable $\textbf{x} = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_D)$ with multiple dimensions and PDF $p_X(\textbf{x})$ and some invertible transformation $\textbf{y} = f(\textbf{x}) = (y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_D)$, their respective PDFs are related through change of variables:

$$ p_Y(\mathbf{y}) = p_X(\mathbf{x}) \left\vert \det \frac{\partial f^{-1}}{\partial \mathbf{x}} (\mathbf{x})\right\vert $$

My question is, does a 'natural' way exist to derive the marginal PDFs for $\textbf{y}$, e.g. $p(y_1)$ via the change of variables transformation, or do we have to brute-force marginalize over the remaining variables like so:

$$ p(y_1) = \int p_X(\textbf{x})  \left\vert \det \frac{\partial f^{-1}}{\partial \mathbf{x}} (\mathbf{x})\right\vert dy_2 dy_3\ldots dy_D$$

I think the answer is that not shortcut exists and we would have to marginalize, because the transformation $f$ may couple the dimensions of $\mathbf{y}$ together, but any more intuitive / theoretical justification would be appreciated.

Comment: The only alternative to this is to directly use the CDF method..

Comment: @AdamO Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: You are overcomplicating the situation.  Ignore all but the first component of $f,$ giving the function $y_1(x_1,\ldots,x_D).$ Compute $\Pr(y_1(X)\le y)$ for arbitrary $y.$  Differentiate the result to obtain its PDF.

Comment: A similar approach is to identify the distribution of $y_1(X)$ by computing directly $\mathbb E[\varphi(y_1(X))]$ for all functions $\varphi(.)$. This is called the ["silent function method"](http://www.lsta.upmc.fr/doct/patra/teaching/LM345_CC2_Corr.pdf) in French, but I am unsure of the English translation.

Comment: @Xi'an In similar contexts, such a function is called a "test function" in English.  Although this has a [standard technical meaning](https://dlmf.nist.gov/1.16#i) in generalized function theory, the term seems like a natural one here, too.